# Pycharm stopped showing output after i changed the project interpreter to Anaconda3

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, pythoninterpreter

I used to work with Pycharm and it was working pretty well till the time I changed the Interpreter to **Anaconda3**. From then onwards whatever I ran gave me no output on the console window.
The console window is just showing this:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

There is something wrong but I am unable to find it.

Comment: Can you give the path of the interpreter you told Pycharm to use?

Comment: 3.6.1 (D:\Anaconda3\python.exe)

Comment: Try making a new environment `conda create --name test python=3` and then `activate test`, you can select "Add Local" in pycharm when choosing the interpreter to choose the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Anaconda is setup properly, validated by opening the terminal within pycharm and checking say for the version of a package that you have installed as part of Anaconda, like I have installed Django as part of virtualenv. I tested that the environment is active in the terminal and tested the version of Django. eg: `python -m django --version` This gave me the version that I expected - `11.3`.

Also this is a site from Anaconda that shows how to get the Anaconda configured for Pycharm, just incase you need it.
https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/pycharm